# postgres "force row level security" executed, but associated policies disabled

Tags: postgresql, row-level-security

In my pg migrations, I execute the following SQL:

```
grant all on all tables in schema denolandia to my_user;
...<create-table>
alter table denolandia.packages force row level security;
create policy update_packages on denolandia.packages for insert
  with check (
    false
  );
```

When I log into Postgres as `my_user` via `psql` and do a `\d` on my schema, I see that on `denolandia.packages` table, the following is reported:

```
Policies (row security disabled):
  POLICY "update_packages" FOR INSERT
    WITH CHECK (false)
```

I just commanded `force row level security`, so why is my policy disabled?

Thanks!

Comment: Shouldn't be first enabled with the ALTER TABLE ENABLE ROW LEVEL SECURITY statement?

Comment: good grief.  yup, that was it.  I was under the impression `force` was a stricter alternative to `enable`.  indeed, _both_ are required :)

Comment: ps, this was a *similar question*, but not a duplicate question as referenced by  a_horse_with_no_name.  nowhere in my problem statement did I mention the table owner.  in fact, my problem was observed by a role that was not the table owner.  my role as described was `my_role`, but the table owner is `postgres` in this case.